# memory allocation for hash map

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I've hashMap with  "Document" as keys and "DocumentSections" as values.`Map <Document, DocumentSection>` . Document has lots of other member variables (primitive and non primitive).Document has also a unique String value. My question is, if it is better to replace the Document as key through  that unique string value from the Document e.g. `HashMap<document.getValue(), DocumentSection>`. where value ist a unique String. Would my program consume less memory, if I use strings as keys and not more the Document object as key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Would my program consume less memory

No, the map only stores references to your Documents. And a reference to a Document or to a String uses the same amount of memory.

Note however that using a mutable object as a key is generally a bad idea. So if your documents can change, from a hashcode/equals perspective, you should probably use that String instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've overwritten my equlas and hashmethode with that unique string value of that Document. So even the Document is mutable, that string value is alwasy constant. So I'm sure there won't be a problem using Document objects as keys. Is that right? or am I wrong on that? Thanks

Comment: Then you can use either methods - they will be equivalent.

Comment: if you have overridden hashcode and equals , if the agreement s followed , nothing to worry , assuming you have done the equals and hashcode carefully

Answer (score 1):

Firstly document is wrong choice as a key, since it is a mutable object.

Second point is that you will not save memory by replacing key with a string reason being document object will stay in memory even if you don't use it as key.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've overwritten my equlas and hashmethode with that unique string value of that Document. So even the Document is mutable, that string value is alwasy constant. So I'm sure there won't be a problem using Document objects as keys. Is that right? or am I wrong on that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you would use string instead of document as keys, hash function may take less time.

Comment: Hi grypp. Thanks. You say "may take less time". ist that an assumption or a fact?

Comment: Considering that the Document's hashcode only calls the String's hashcode, it won't make a difference.